# How does c# handle async void

Tags: c#, async-await

I generally program webservers and at first I thought that there must be continuous chain of methods that return task, so stuff up the stack may ask database if it is done.

Recently I saw wpf code, that does something like that:

```
    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
    }
```

Called in event handler. UI seems to be responsive, so I guess it does work. How does it work? How does this translate to aspnet?

Answer (score 11):

I explain how `async void` methods work - and why they should be avoided - in my [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) article.

`async void` has the same semantics as `async Task`, except for exceptions. An `async void` method will capture the current `SynchronizationContext` at the beginning of the method, and any exceptions from that method will be captured and raised directly on that captured context. In the most common scenarios, this will cause an application-level exception, usually a crash. Some people call `async void` methods "fire-and-forget", but because of their exceptional behavior, I prefer "fire-and-crash". :)

"Avoid async void" is the general guideline, with one notable exception: event handlers (or items that are logically event handlers, such as `ICommand.Execute` implementations).

> How does it work? How does this translate to aspnet?

It works just like any other `async` method. The main platform difference is that the UI thread *doesn't need to know* when the `async` method completes. ASP.NET needs to know that so it knows when to send the request, but the UI has no need to know when the `async` method completes. So `async void` works. It's still best avoided, because the *calling* code usually *does* need to know when it completes.

Answer (score 6):

Async void is only to be used for event handler/delegate comparability. that Execute is a event callback, likely from a `DelegateCommand` or similar.

The way it works is it treats it exactly the same as if you had a function that returned a `Task` but the caller never called `await` on that returned task.

On ASP.NET you are likely to never use async void and instead be using controllers that expose methods that return a [`Task<ActionResult>`](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4), use [`HostingEnviorment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/), or using functions that are wrapped up in a [`Page.RegisterAsyncTask`](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45) in situations where you would have used `async void` in normal desktop programming.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(LoadSomeData));
}
```

Comment: What happens when I do not await the task?

Comment: @user2029276 the asp.net subsystem does not know about the task and may tear down the app domain for the website before the function has completed executing causing the work you told the function to do to be lost and never completed. The reason you can get away with this in WPF is your AppDomain won't get randomly torn down while the user is  using the program, as long as the program is running the AppDomain lives on. A inactive user on a asp.net site could have a AppDomain torn down and not even notice it happen.