# Why isn't SmtpClient.SendAsync async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpClient.cs#L583

This method is marked as asynchronous but returns void. Is it actually asynchronous and just isn't Task based? If so, how is it asynchronous?

Comment: Because it would conceived and implemented way before TBA was a part of the run-time

Comment: No downvote included, though i did make an obvious typo

Comment: Not sure why they chose async void, but async void is explained pretty well in this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685636/how-does-c-sharp-handle-async-void

Comment: You can of course use `client.SendMailAsync()` :)

Comment: @mariocatch `SendAsync` is not an `async void`; its a *pre*-`async`/`await`, event based asynchronous method. OTOH, `SendMailAsync` appropriately returns a `Task` because it's designed around the TPL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some info about your particular question on this method at the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync?view=netframework-4.7.1) page.

> To receive notification when the e-mail has been sent or the operation has been canceled, add an event handler to the `SendCompleted` event.

It means method is not blocking, but can't be awaited, because it knows nothing about TPL. You should subscribe to a `SendCompleted` event instead.
Check the code example by link I've provided to see possible usage scenario.

While [`SendMailAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=netframework-4.7.1) is implemented with task based asynchronous pattern and, probably, should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you read that code, you probably overlooked AsyncOpManager - see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpClient.cs#L662 :)

However, in fact, in a `switch` just below, we see that:

- SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis: always throws
- SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory: seems 100% synchronous (direct call to `message.Send(_writer, true, allowUnicode)` and `writer.Close` and `_transport.ReleaseConnection`)
- SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network/default: seems 100% asynchronous (`_transport.BeginGetConnection` starts operation, I don't see any wait or continuation)

(at least if I read the code well, I didn't dig too deep there)